# MYSQL JSON Path field issue

Tags: mysql

Looks like we've had an update to our DB, where there is a specification of a field. What I use to use now doesnt work, because the field is now database.encounterID. So this doesn't work:

```
select b.config->'$.encounterId' AS eid
from bencounter be \G
```

I tried using:

```
select b.config->'$dabase.encounterId' AS eid
from bencounter be \G
```

and it doesn't work.

Thoughts?

Comment: Really, how do you expect us to help based on this question? Show us the schema, and an example of a few rows from the table at least, we are not clairvoyant

Answer (score 0):

Quote paths with special symbols.

Example:

> ```
> WITH bencounter AS ( 
>     SELECT '{"database.encounterId":12345, "database.encounterName":"abcde"}' AS config
> )
> select b.config->'$."database.encounterId"' AS eid,
>        b.config->'$."database.encounterName"' AS ename
> from bencounter b
> ```
>
> ```
> eid   | ename  
> :---- | :------
> 12345 | "abcde"
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a6abd94c07ba1f1ff05030de902d91a)*